# Accurately evaluating the hypergeometric function

Tags: numerics, special-functions, machine-precision, arbitrary-precision

As part of another problem, I am working to evaluate hypergeometric functions such as

```
Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, n, -1]
```

for large $n$.  I am hoping to obtain at least double-precision accuracy all the way through `n = 1600`.  However, starting as low as `n = 200`, I obtain precision errors:

```
N[Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, 200, -1], 17]
N::meprec: Internal precision limit
```

Are there ways to tell *Mathematica* it can use as much time as it wants to compute this quantity? Or are there any other workarounds?

Comment: Try this `Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 100}, 
 N[Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, 200, -1], 17]]`

Comment: Better: `Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, 200, N[-1, 17]]`. The problem is that `N[]` is by default unable to cope with the exact result being returned by `Hypergeometric2F1[]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before people get any ideas: although we have the identity:

$${}_2 F_1\left({{1,1}\atop{m}}\mid -1\right)=\frac{m-1}{2}\Phi\left(\frac12,1,m-1\right)$$

where $\Phi(z,s,a)$ is the Lerch transcendent; or, in *Mathematica* notation:

```
Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, m, -1] == (m - 1) HurwitzLerchPhi[1/2, 1, m - 1]/2
```

the computation becomes even more unstable with that replacement (I'm not really sure why); don't use it.

In any event, we have the relations

$$\begin{align*}
{}_2 F_1\left({{1,1}\atop{m}}\mid -1\right)&=2^{m-2}(m-1)\sum_{k=m-1}^\infty \frac1{k 2^k}\\
&=2^{m-2}(m-1)\left(\log\,2-\sum_{k=1}^{m-2}\frac1{k 2^k}\right)
\end{align*}$$

where we see why `N[]` might have a spot of trouble with evaluating the exact expression produced by `Hypergeometric2F1[]`: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m-2}\frac1{k 2^k}\approx \log\,2$, with the difference getting smaller as $m\to\infty$, and we thus see a fair amount of catastrophic cancellation during numerical evaluation. In particular, for $m=200$, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m-2}\frac1{k 2^k}$ and $\log\,2$ agree to $61$ (!) decimal places.

Fortunately for us, `Hypergeometric2F1[]` can cope nicely with inexact arguments:

```
Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, N[200, 20], -1]
   0.9950490265763910737
```

In short: just supply inexact numbers to `Hypergeometric2F1[]` at the outset.

Answer (score 0):

Using something very unfancy like the Gauss hypergeometric ascending series will easily solve this problem.  See http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.2 .  It took me 12 terms for double-precision accuracy for n=200 and 8 terms for n=1600.